# Python 3 Creating a column based on variables from other columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, calculated-columns

I have a dataset that has the year, month and day of the week. However, it is missing the actual day of the month (i.e. from day 1 - 30). The dataset is as follow:

```
#   Year    Month   Day_Of_Week
22024   2002    January Tuesday
22101   2002    January Wednesday
22146   2002    January Thursday
22201   2002    January Friday
22247   2002    January Saturday
22280   2002    January Sunday
22335   2002    January Monday
22383   2002    January Tuesday
22384   2002    January Wednesday
22424   2002    January Thursday
22459   2002    January Friday
22511   2002    January Saturday
22598   2002    January Sunday
22599   2002    January Monday
22686   2002    January Tuesday
22687   2002    January Wednesday
22688   2002    January Wednesday
22689   2002    January Wednesday
22761   2002    January Wednesday
22762   2002    January Wednesday
22763   2002    January Wednesday
22764   2002    January Wednesday
22765   2002    January Thursday
22766   2002    January Thursday
22767   2002    January Thursday
22768   2002    January Thursday
22814   2002    January Friday
22815   2002    January Friday
22816   2002    January Friday
22817   2002    January Friday
22818   2002    January Friday
```

The logic for finding the day is very easy. The first record in the table is for day 1. The second record is for day 2 and we increase the days whenever the "Day_Of_Week" is changed from the previous record.
When the month is "January" we count 31 days, "February" we count 28 days and so on.

Using pandas, I want to create a new column called "Crash_Day". How can I iterate over the records and populate my records in my new column following my logic above?

How can I construct a for loop or so to read the record of each column and populate the new column accordingly?

This is my code so far

```
import pandas as pd

crash_data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print('Length: {} rows.'.format(len(crash_data)))
print(crash_data.head())
```

If someone is interested to look at the data, it is in the following link:
**[Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d9c4kui2WRuEaligaNFdo4TegchZ8bg4/view?usp=sharing)**

Comment: What I would do would be to take your day of the week column, and compare it to itself but shifted one. Then wherever it's different is when it changes days. If you write wherever it's different into a new columns as 1s and 0s, then you can take a cumulative sum of that column and that will count up all the days (constantly increasing). And then you can figure out how to transform that column (something like [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, ...., 31, 31, 32, 32, 33, ...]) to wrapping correctly at the months (could do the exact same thing with the months to reset that counter, actually..)

Comment: Not that the above method is particularly efficient. I just haven't worked with the date stuff in Pandas well enough to give a better answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for stopping by Alexander. The below code did the trick ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all dates are consecutive and no missing between them, is possible use lambda function with compare [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) (`!=`) for starts of each consecutive value and then use [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for `counter`:

```
df['day'] = (df.groupby(['Year','Month'])['Day_Of_Week']
               .transform(lambda x: x.ne(x.shift()).cumsum()))
```

Alternative solution:

```
s = df['Day_Of_Week'].ne(df['Day_Of_Week'].shift())
df['day'] = s.groupby([df['Year'],df['Month']]).cumsum().astype(int)
```

---

```
print (df)
       Year     Month Day_Of_Week  day
22024  2002   January     Tuesday    1
22101  2002   January   Wednesday    2
22146  2002   January    Thursday    3
22201  2002   January      Friday    4
22247  2002   January    Saturday    5
22280  2002   January      Sunday    6
22335  2002   January      Monday    7
22383  2002   January     Tuesday    8
22384  2002   January   Wednesday    9
22424  2002   January    Thursday   10
22459  2002   January      Friday   11
22511  2002   January    Saturday   12
22598  2002   January      Sunday   13
22599  2002   January      Monday   14
22686  2002   January     Tuesday   15
22687  2002   January   Wednesday   16
22688  2002   January   Wednesday   16
22689  2002   January   Wednesday   16
22761  2002   January   Wednesday   16
22762  2002   January   Wednesday   16
22763  2002   January   Wednesday   16
22764  2002   January   Wednesday   16
22765  2002   January    Thursday   17
22766  2002   January    Thursday   17
22767  2002   January    Thursday   17
22768  2002   January    Thursday   17
22814  2002   January      Friday   18
22815  2002   January      Friday   18
22816  2002   January      Friday   18
22817  2002   January      Friday   18
22818  2002   January      Friday   18
22817  2002  February   Wednesday    1
22818  2002  February   Wednesday    1
```

Comment: You are amazing jezrael, really appreciate your help